# Can only concatenate list (not"tuple") to list /Error, while importing OBJ

Tags: python, import

I'm trying to import an OBJ format I exported from Rhino.

It used to work without any troubles, but now this shows up.

I went to the file and opened it with note++, but don't know hat to do next.

[image: This is the error]

This is line 809:

```
nu.points.foreach_set("co", [co_axis for vt_idx in curv_idx for co_axis in (vert_loc[vt_idx] + (1.0,))])
```